# Cannot detect Dropdown value before run the script Laravel 5.7

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to detect if dropdown selected value changed to run the calculate script because it must be different if it is Issue case or Refund case

now if i make any change on dropdown nothing happens no change in label text and no change on calculation

here is my blade file code :

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                                    <label>@lang('site.action_type')</label>
                                    <select class="form-control select2 action-type" style="width: 100%;"
                                            name="action_type"
                                            id="action_type">
                                        <option selected value="issue">@lang('site.issue')</option>
                                        <option value="reissue">@lang('site.reissue')</option>
                                        <option value="emd">@lang('site.emd')</option>
                                        <option value="refund">@lang('site.refund')</option>
                                        {{--                                            <option value="void_charge">@lang('site.void_charge')</option>--}}
                                    </select>
                                </div>

 <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="fare">@lang('site.fare')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="fare" class="form-control "
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   name="fare" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeyup="findTotal()"
                                                   onfocus="this.value=''"
                                                   value="0" >
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="tax">@lang('site.tax')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="tax" class="form-control"
                                                   name="tax" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   onkeyup="findTotal()"
                                                   onfocus="this.value=''"
                                                   value="0" >
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="k7">@lang('site.k7')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="k7" class="form-control"
                                                   name="k7" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   onkeyup="findTotal()"
                                                   onfocus="this.value=''"
                                                   value="0" >
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="comm">@lang('site.comm')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="comm" class="form-control"
                                                   name="comm" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   onkeyup="findTotal()"
                                                   onfocus="this.value=''"
                                                   value="0" >
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="profit">@lang('site.profit')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="number" id="profit" class="form-control"
                                                   name="profit" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onblur="findTotal()"
                                                   onkeyup="findTotal()"
                                                   value="{{ number_format(old('profit'), 2) }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="total_tax">@lang('site.total_tax')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="total_tax" class="form-control"
                                                   name="total_tax" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onkeyup="return sum(event)"
                                                   value="{{ old('total_tax') }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="col-md-2">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="total_cost">@lang('site.total_cost')</label>
                                        <div class="position-relative has-icon-left">
                                            <input type="text" id="total_cost" class="form-control"
                                                   name="total_cost" placeholder="0"
                                                   onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)"
                                                   onkeyup="return sum(event)"
                                                   value="{{ old('total_cost') }}" readonly>
                                            <div class="form-control-position">
                                                <i class="la la-keyboard-o"></i>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

and here is my Script code :

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

    function findTotal() {
        $('.action-type').change(function () {

            var action_value = $(this).val();

            if (action_value == 'RFND') {
                var fare_val = $("#fare").val();
                var tax_val = $("#tax").val();
                var vat_val = $("#k7").val();
                var comm_val = $("#comm").val();
                var sale_price_val = $("#sale_price").val();
                var total_tax = parseFloat(tax_val) + parseFloat(vat_val);
                var total_net =-(parseFloat(fare_val) + parseFloat(tax_val) + parseFloat(vat_val)) ;
                var prft_val = (parseFloat(total_net) - (parseFloat(sale_price_val) + parseFloat(comm_val))) ;
                $('#total_tax').val(total_tax);
                $('#total_cost').val(total_net);
                $('#profit').val(prft_val);

                $('#salePrice_lbl').prop('value', 'Give To Passenger');
            } else if (action_value == 'EMD') {

            } else {
                var fare_val = $("#fare").val();
                var tax_val = $("#tax").val();
                var vat_val = $("#k7").val();
                var comm_val = $("#comm").val();
                var sale_price_val = $("#sale_price").val();
                var total_tax = parseFloat(tax_val) + parseFloat(vat_val);
                var total_net = parseFloat(fare_val) + parseFloat(tax_val) + parseFloat(vat_val);
                var prft_val = parseFloat(sale_price_val) - (parseFloat(total_net)+ parseFloat(comm_val));
                $('#total_tax').val(total_tax);
                $('#total_cost').val(total_net);
                $('#profit').val(prft_val);

            }
        });

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the element class instead of an ID or name.

'.action_type' will ask jQuery to look for an element with the class "action_type". It should be '#action_type'. I think that's all I see at the moment... Try that out, and good luck!

Comment: Agreed, but the code posted only has a single element with the `action-type` class so that advice doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

First thank you all for trying helping me

Second i fixed it

the dropdown value was wrong it was looking for RFND value but option value is Refund

and i change the script to be like this:

```
        function findTotal() {
        var ddl = document.getElementById("action_type");
        var selectedValue = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value;
        if (selectedValue == "refund")
        {
            var fare_val = $("#fare").val();
            var tax_val = $("#tax").val();
            var vat_val = $("#k7").val();
            var comm_val = $("#comm").val();
            var sale_price_val = $("#sale_price").val();
            var total_net =-((parseFloat(fare_val) + parseFloat(tax_val))- parseFloat(comm_val) ) ;
            var prft_val = -((parseFloat(total_net) + (parseFloat(sale_price_val) + parseFloat(comm_val)))) ;
            var total_vat =  parseFloat(vat_val) +  (parseFloat(prft_val)/21);

            $('#total_vat').val(total_vat);
            $('#total_cost').val(total_net);
            $('#profit').val(prft_val);
            document.getElementById('salePrice_lbl').innerHTML =`@lang('site.give_to_pass')` ;
            // $('#salePrice_lbl').prop('value', 'Give To Passenger');

        }else {
            var fare_val = $("#fare").val();
            var tax_val = $("#tax").val();
            var vat_val = $("#k7").val();
            var comm_val = $("#comm").val();
            var sale_price_val = $("#sale_price").val();
            var total_net = (parseFloat(fare_val) + parseFloat(tax_val)) - parseFloat(comm_val);
            var prft_val = parseFloat(sale_price_val) - parseFloat(total_net);
            var total_vat =  parseFloat(vat_val) +  (parseFloat(prft_val)/21);

            $('#total_vat').val(total_vat);
            $('#total_cost').val(total_net);
            $('#profit').val(prft_val);
            document.getElementById('salePrice_lbl').innerHTML = `@lang('site.sale_price')`;
        }


    }
```

and now every thing is working fine

thank you again :)